# how to store a parsed .xslx file in a dto

Tags: java, excel, dto

Code:parses through the excel file using poi and prints the output in the console and also creates a new excel file to show the output.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileName);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row ;
    XSSFCell cell;


    Iterator<Row>  rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while(rows.hasNext())
    {
        row = (XSSFRow)rows.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
        while(cells.hasNext())
        {
            cell = (XSSFCell)cells.next();

            switch(cell.getCellType()) 
            {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"\t\t");
            break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()+ "\t\t");
            break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t\t");
            break;
            }

        }System.out.println("");
    }fileName.close();  

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C://data.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
```

Output:
Id
Name
Location
Role
Salary

111.0
Kumar
Chennai
Developer
1000.0

112.0
Larsen
Bangalore
Developer
2000.0

Queries: 
 1. How to get the output in the same format as in excel?
 2. How to store the output in a DTO object?

Answer (score 0):

try this way to add Values DTO

Create one Student DTO with properties like and setter and getters with `Id,Name,Location,Role,Salary`

```
     while(rows.hasNext())
            {
                row = (XSSFRow)rows.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
    StudentDTO std = new StudentDTO();
                while(cells.hasNext())
                {
                    cell = (XSSFCell)cells.next();

                    switch(cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN: System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"\t\t");
    std.setId(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()+ "\t\t");
    std.setName(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue()+ "\t\t");
std.setLocation(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                    }

                }System.out.println("");
            }
```